# Allow Feedburner subscription for xml feeds

Tags: php, xml, rss, feedburner

I have a website, that generates several xml feeds for various types of content in the site.
I want to know, how can i allow the end users to subscribe to each of the xml feeds via feedburner. An example url is: `http://www.example.com/articles.xml`

I referred to [**this guide**](http://theedublogger.com/2010/01/26/setting-up-feedburner-rss-and-email-subscription-for-your-blog/), and so far, i have setup a feedburner account for my site, and it just asked my website url, so that i have given only my domain name.

Is it possible to specify an xml url for my website, in order to allow users to subscribe to it via feedburner ? Or is there any feedburner form code that i can integrate in my website, to allow users to subscribe to an xml url in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it ask for your website URL or the feed URL?

Just follow any tutorial on how to burn RSS feeds on Feedburner, like this one at http://www.northernpride.com/blog/website-design/how-to-burn-your-rss-feed-using-feedburner/.

After burning your own RSS feeds you'll get feedburner URLs which you can then use on your website so visitors will subscribe to them instead of using the original URLs.

Comment: Well, thanks for that first line in your answer. Initially i have just mentioned my website url under the "Original Feed". But i later edited it and mentioned my xml url. I hope it is fine now.

Comment: Do you still have a problem? You should now have everything you need to publish the feedburner feeds on your website and allow the visitors to subscribe to them.

Comment: Everything is fine now. Can we create multiple feed urls in feedburner and have unlimited subscriptions? Is it free or any hidden fees applicable after some time?

Comment: It's free and I don't know of any limitations in regards of number of feeds and subscriptions.